In some cases, "this" in the function passed as an argument to the higher order function is Window or undefined. Please tell me the difference
class Foo {
  
  m(f) {
    f();
  }
}
let foo = new Foo();


foo.m(function () {
  console.log(this);
  // Window
});

class Foo {
  
  m(f) {
    f();
  }
}

class Boo {
 
  m2() {
    let foo = new Foo();

    foo.m(function () {
      console.log(this);
      // undefined
    });
  }
}
let boo = new Boo();
boo.m2();

Why are the two results different?
I think this should be undefined in both because they are called in a function format rather than an object calling them in a method format like o.method(). If Window is calling it implicitly, why is the second code undefined?
I looked up lexical context and execution, but it was too difficult to understand.
In the case of arrow functions, it was possible to predict what "this" would be, but in the case of anonymous functions, it was not possible to predict.

Always use strict mode! (Classes are implicitly in strict mode.)

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#no_this_substitution But the short version is that in loose mode, f() calls f with this set to the global object, but in strict mode, f() calls f with this set to undefined.

@T.J.Crowder It's not the call that is relevant, f() always calls f with no this. It's f itself that, when not using strict mode, defaults the value to the global object

@Bergi - True, that's slightly more technically correct (sloppy phrasing on my part, pun intended). What matters is whether the function was created in strict mode (in an already-strict context, or with "use strict" at the top of the function body).

@Ry- When invoked as a standalone function (not attached to an object: func()), this typically refers to the global object (in non-strict mode) or undefined (in strict mode).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
I think both of my code called inside class as standalone. so it's called in strict mode and both should be undefined. but why first is Window?

The behavior is determined by whether the function is in strict mode, not the call to it.
